# How to shut down application after BeanCreationException is thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

During the startup process, my application creates bean which schedules some tasks in task executor, and then it fails after creating another bean.
This  leaves my application in undead state where application looks like it's running but does not provide functionality. 
I wonder how I could handle BeanCreationException globally to provide proper shutdown.

This is my example code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public Application(){
        executorService.submit(()-> {while(true);});
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
     }
}

@Service
public class FaultyService {
    public FaultyService(){
        throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a @PreDestroy to shut down the executor. However, it is still the responsibility of your threads to respond to `Thread.interrupt()` so your infinite while-loop would not be killed, but yours is just a contrived example so I've changed that too:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public Application() {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            while (true)
            {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) break;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void tearDownExecutor() {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}

@Service
public class FaultyService {
    public FaultyService(){
        throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }
}
```